# Why isn't the "RAP - Reuse Attack Protector" in the mainline Linux kernel?

Tags: memory, protection, kernel

https://grsecurity.net/rap_announce_ret.php

https://grsecurity.net/download.php#test

**Q:** If the RAP - Reuse Attack Protector - is such an extreme great idea, why isn't it already included in the mainline Linux kernel? **What is missing to make the word a much more secure place?**

Marketing? Political issues? Technical issues? Licence issues? or what?

Comment: RAP is still experimental. Implementing it in GRSec lets early adopters try it out. If it works and doesn't break stuff, it will make the mainline kernel in due course.

Comment: Adding to @paj28's comment above, it's not unusual for new features to be distributed as patchsets first for brave people to try out, and once they have received some degree of real-world testing, the process of integrating those patches into the mainline kernel can continue.

Comment: There is also various politics involved. While there is no doubt that the grsecurity patches increase the security they cost some performance. But, there are developers which are critical about even the slightest performance impact while others see security as more important.

Comment: The biggest problem is that it requires a massive amount of modification to the kernel, even if the modifications are trivial (correcting bad casting for function pointers). That means every single driver and subsystem maintainer has to get off their ass and fix up all their code. Even if each individual fix is easy, there's pretty much no way every maintainer could, or would, do that. It would have to be made a mandatory part of the Linux kernel coding style, and would still take a long time.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Actually RAP itself is incredibly fast with virtually no performance impact. SSP has a far higher impact, even. The commercial version is supposed to be even faster (and provide better coverage), but given how expensive even regular grsecurity is now, I imagine the commercial version is next to unobtainable by most.